# Excel Countif with the first count only

Tags: excel, countif

I am using CountIf to find the number of duplicate values in a column. First I sorted the values in ascending order. Then I apply =COUNTIF(B:B;B2) and dragged it till end. The Results are as:

[image]

However, I don't want the values multiple times in the column C. Just need it for one time. Also is it possible without sorting the column B in ascending order?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
=if(countif(b$2:b2, b2)=1, countif(b:b, b2), text(,))
```

Fill down. The data does not require sorting.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) =IF(COUNTIF(B$2:B2; B2)=1;COUNTIF(B:B; B2);TEXT(;)) worked perfect

Comment: Mea culpa; I didn't notice the semi-colon list separator in your sample formula (e.g. `=COUNTIF(B:B; B2)`). Glad you got it working.